# fb.ui post to wall not working

Tags: php, facebook, fb.ui

So, I'm using the FB API to post a message to a user's wall. My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.ui({ 
        method: 'post', 
        message: 'Testing Message',
        caption: 'This is the Caption value.',
        name: 'Testing JS feed dialog on Antoher Feed',
        link: 'http://anotherfeed.com?ref=link',
        description: 'Testing property links, and action links via Feed Dialog Javascript SDK',
        picture: 'https://shawnsspace.com/ShawnsSpace.toon.nocolor..png',
        properties: 
        [
            { 
                text: 'Link Test 1', href: 'http://anotherfeed.com?ref=1'
            },
            { 
                text: 'Link Test 2', href: 'http://anotherfeed.com?ref=2'
            },
        ],
        actions: 
        [
            { 
                name: 'Shawn', link: 'http://anotherfeed.com'
            }
        ]       
    });
</script>
```

Doesn't work... any ideas?

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't give any info to provide you solution. Explain clearly what is the issue, what error message you can see in console etc?

Comment: NO error messages are given. Typically, another window is supposed to pop up and prompt you if it's okay to post on the wall. But, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
FB.ui({ 
        method: 'post',
```

to

```
FB.ui({ 
        method: 'feed',
```

[Example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Comment: Do you have Facebook initialized in your code? check the example I have posted in my answer (link)

Comment: Yes, I do. However, when I open the JS console on chrome, I get the message "GET http://sportannica.com/connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js 404 (Not Found) "

Comment: you are not loading the script properly. Check the example

Comment: Got it!! Thank you for having patience with my absent mindedness. I've been told that it can be frustrating at times.

Comment: IS there any way that I could achieve the same results thru php?

Comment: Okay. So assuming that I have publish_stream permission, what would the code need to look like?